# why we write ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();

Tags: arraylist

We define a new arraylist of strings as

```
ArrayList<String> listname=new ArrayList<>;
```

but when we have to define an arraylist for integers, why we are writing

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: A list of integers is actually declared as ArrayList<Integer>. ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> declares a list which contains lists of integers.

Answer (score 0):

This line -

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

is equivalent to this -

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

because of Type Inference in Java Generics.

Type inference is a process by which the JVM can automatically infer the target generic type from the context. From the [official Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) -

> Type inference is a Java compiler's ability to look at each method
>   invocation and corresponding declaration to determine the type
>   argument (or arguments) that make the invocation applicable.

In your first example, you are assigning the newly created `ArrayList<>` to a reference of type `ArrayList<String>`. From the context, the Java compiler can determine that the type argument for the `new ArrayList<>` will be String. Similar reasoning also applies for the second example.